# App for Android or iOS to backup photos from a certain time period ONLY

Tags: backup, photography

This year I am in charge of planning my family's reunion, but there are some members of the family who can't come. The ones who can't have requested that we take lots of pictures so they can feel like they participated vicariously.

I agree with this sentiment, but I have gone through similar situations and trying to get everyone to upload photos from their various devices for a particular event is like trying to herd cats. People often forget or, in the case of this family, older generations simply have no idea how to do so.

So I am searching for an app that I could request members of the family to install on their various devices that would automatically back up any photos they take during the course of the reunion to a specified server. And ONLY during the specified dates. Then (ideally) once the final date was finished the app would uninstall itself.

I have looked at various "Wedding" apps that claim to do this, but they all back up to proprietary servers and charge to actually get the photos back. And the 'free' ones I've seen also include a watermark unless you pony up for the premium version. Since I'm a cheapskate and like to have control of my own data, I am adverse to using these options.

So here is my criteria:

1. App must be free.
2. It must back up photos to a remote server.
3. It must do this ONLY for photos taken during a specified time period.
4. The remote server is one that I can control. FTP, perhaps? Not totally necessary, but I must be able to get the pictures off of the server without paying for it.
5. (Pipe Dream) Once the time period is over, the app uninstalls itself.
   If such an app doesn't exist (which I suspect is the case), I may pony up myself and write it, but I thought I'd check to see if this community has any suggestions before I try to re-invent the wheel.

Thank you in advance!